# What does findAll do when it has no argument?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to understand a python code. It has a statement

```
soup.findAll()
```

where `soup` is a `Beautifulsoup object`

I printed the type and length of result which was

type : `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

length = `1359`

What is findAll matching against here ?

Comment: Can you iterate through it and see what it contains?

Comment: @Alberto, No, it's too huge, and moreover the content is html source code of some zomato url, hence it is very difficult for me to decipher where an element ends and the other starts

Comment: Obviously it contains all the html separated into different elements, you are not looking for any particular element so it retuns them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers enough:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup('<div>some text</div>').findAll()

[<html><body><div>some text</div></body></html>,
 <body><div>some text</div></body>,
 <div>some text</div>]
```

It finds all children, that is, the upper element `html`, the inner element `body`, and the innermost element, the `div`. This is what findAll does, it finds all the children of a soup object, on all levels matching the argument, the argument here is "empty" so it matches everything.

Note that creating an object with BeautifulSoup will add `html` and `body` if they are not present.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really figure it out by looking through [the source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/infrastructure/trunk/projects/stats/BeautifulSoup.py) , but it either *lists* all child tags or none. `ResultSet`  is a subclass of list so if the length is greater than zero then I would guess it is returning ALL child tags and there is no search criteria.  `ResultSet` has a `source` attribute which is a `SoupStrainer` object that *contains* the search parameters in the `attrs` attribute. Try

```
result = soup.findAll()
print result.source
```